# Rust: ".. does not live long enough"

Tags: rust, scope, lifetime

Here is the code (with a Rust beginner difficulty):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait TIndex<'a> {
    // cut
}

pub struct HashMapIndex<'a> {
    pub filter_by_keyword: HashMap<String, &'a str> // simplified (and ugly)
}

impl<'a> TIndex<'a> for HashMapIndex<'a> {
    // cut
}

pub struct Matcher<'a> {
    pub index: &'a RefCell<Box<dyn TIndex<'a> + 'a>>
}

impl<'a> Matcher<'a> {
    pub fn new(index: &'a RefCell<Box<dyn TIndex<'a> + 'a>>) -> Self {
        Matcher {
            index
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let index = HashMapIndex {
        filter_by_keyword: HashMap::new()
    };
    let boxed_index: Box<dyn TIndex> = Box::new(index);
    let refcell = RefCell::from(boxed_index);
    let mut _matcher = Matcher::new(
        &refcell // `refcell` does not live long enough
    );
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c31e897e27ce7e18ddbcf85672e5d290)

I'm not sure i understand what is wrong (but something is definitely).
`'a` is a `main()` function scope here, `index` and `refcell` live until main() exits. `matcher` accepts a reference to `RefCell` that lives at least `'a` and references to a box that lives at least `'a` and point to a `TIndex` trait object that lives at least `'a` and whose internals live at least `'a`.

How should it be changed (and what's wrong in lifetimes declarations here)?

PS. I'm getting a compiler hint (at `main()` closing `}`):

```
    }
    | -
    | |
    | `refcell` dropped here while still borrowed
    | borrow might be used here, when `refcell` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `RefCell<Box<dyn TIndex<'_>>>`
```

not sure i understand it as `refcell` is passed by reference (borrowed by `_matcher`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not sure i understand it as refcell is passed by reference (borrowed by _matcher).

The problem is that you're defining `Matcher` such that the lifetimes of the `RefCell` and the lifetime of the *contents* of the `RefCell` must be the same.

This means you're telling rustc the `RefCell` must live as long what it contains, meaning once you've put the `RefCell` inside the `Matcher`... your program can't work anymore, because a container can't rightly outlive its contents.

You need to split your lifetimes so rustc knows how they nest, at the very least you need to give a different lifetime to the `&RefCell` and its contents -- and tell rustc that the contents outlive the `&RefCell`:

```rust
pub struct Matcher<'a, 'b> {
    pub index: &'a RefCell<Box<dyn TIndex<'b> + 'b>>
}

impl<'a, 'b: 'a> Matcher<'a, 'b> {
    pub fn new(index: &'a RefCell<Box<dyn TIndex<'b> + 'b>>) -> Self {
        Matcher {
            index
        }
    }
}
```

It might also be a good idea to split the lifetime parameter of the `TIndex` and the lifetime bound of the `TIndex` (the contents of the TIndex should outlive *it*), but it doesn't seem necessary for the repro you've posted here.

Comment: does it mean every time where we have a *reference* to something ('a here) that accepts lifetime (*content*, 'b' here) we need to separate lifetimes?

Comment: Pretty much yeah, though it's also a factor of the container  being parameterized on that lifetime.

Comment: what if a new parameterized structure with a ref to `Matcher` is added - does it mean a new lifetime should be added too, eg `pub struct CombinedMatcher<'a, 'b, 'c> {
    pub matcher: &'a Matcher<'b, 'c>
}`?